FET selection and quantity for buck-boost converter design
I am working on designing a buck-boost converter where the input voltage is 24 V regulated, and the output voltage ranges from 12 to 48 V with a current rating of 5 A. The design should also allow for easy adjustment when the output voltage is set to a fixed value.
Here's my approach to selecting the FET and determining the number needed:

For the high side and low side of the buck portion, I've chosen the CSD18543Q3A FET, which has VDS = 60 V and ID = 35 A. I selected this FET to ensure that it can handle at least twice the input voltage, which is 24 V.
Since the VDS of the selected FET is less than 2 x 48 V (the maximum output voltage), I decided not to use the same FET for the high side and low side of the boost. Instead, I chose the CSD19531Q5A, which has VDS = 100 V and IDS = 100 A. This FET has a higher voltage rating than needed, but it addresses the voltage requirement. However, it may result in size issues due to its high current rating.
Here's where I'm encountering uncertainty: Do I need more than one FET, for example, for the higher FET in the buck switch? The datasheet specifies a power dissipation (PD) of 66 W at 25°C. Considering that in the buck configuration, Vin = 24 V and I = 5 A, which gives a power dissipation of 120 W, would I need two FETs to handle this power?


Is your SMPS monolithic and if so, have you considered internal HS/LS FETs?

@ Colin
No, there is no internal switch, and my goal is to understand, in a general way, how the FETs have been selected. My design is using LT8390, but I have tried to ask in a broader context.

Your FETs don't (i.e. shouldn't) dissipate 120 W -- when ON, the current may be 5 A, but the VDS will be low (100s mV), and when off, the VDS will be high, but the current nearly zero.
Properly designed, one FET is sufficient.

Thank you. Also, do you agree with # 2? I cannot use the same FET as in p#1 for the boost portion because it requires a higher VDS. Is that correct?

Also, is RDS(ON)xcurrent (I) compared with the power dissipation specified in the datasheet? The value for power dissipation is usually quite high, and I don't see any scenario where we would need more than one FET.
